# Find out if decimal point is present in decimal data type

Tags: .net

I have a decimal data type.

I am getting values in multiple formats like 25 or 25.00.

How do I check if decimal point is presnet in a given decimal number?

If it's not present I have to add .00 to the number.

Comment: you seem to be confusing display with internal representation...

Comment: @MitchWheat: Not necessarily. The internal representation of 25m is different to that of 25.0m, which is different to that of 25.00m.

Comment: @MitchWheat: `Decimal` isn't `Double`.  This should be possible.

Comment: You can see quite a few questions were not answered for my request. What is upvote?

Comment: If it's a solution to my question I am clicking a checkbox. I still didn't get when to click on upvote?

Comment: @user228777: You can only accept a single answer (the most helpful one) whereas you can upvote any number of answers - and so can other people. (Only the person who asked the question can accept an answer.)

Comment: @SLaks: I understand that decimal is not double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but I believe this does what you want unconditionally:

```
decimal twoDp = decimal.Round((original / 100) * 100, 2);
```

That certainly works for me:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShowRounded(25m);
        ShowRounded(25.0m);
        ShowRounded(25.00m);
        ShowRounded(25.000m);
    }

    static void ShowRounded(decimal d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round((d / 100) * 100, 2));
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, if this is *only* for display:

```
string formatted = value.ToString("0.00");
```

Or for display as currency, with the current cultural settings:

```
string formatted = value.ToString("c");
```

Comment: +1, reading between the lines he probably just wants it *displayed* with `.00`.

Comment: Jon, I think I may have misclicked(sp)... sorry about that.  I undid my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You are "getting values" in multiple formats. So you're getting strings in other words? I'm not exactly sure what you're ultimately asking for, but if you want to format the number as currency, you can do this:

```
decimal d = 25;
Console.WriteLine("{0:c}", d);

string d2 = "$25";
Console.WriteLine("{0:c}", decimal.Parse(d2, NumberStyles.Currency));

string d3 = "$25.00";
Console.WriteLine("{0:c}", decimal.Parse(d3, NumberStyles.Currency));
```

Comment: It's a long story - I get this value from middle tier ( multiple vendors) but my object has a amount as datatype decimal.. In that object sometimes I get value as 25 for $ 25 and sometimes 25.00 for same value. but other program always expects value in 25.00 format. So Whatever I get I have to always fromat in dollar.cents format.